# Blazor WebAssembly Publush Fails: Unrecognized command or argument

Tags: visual-studio, publish, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor webassembly project that has suddenly decided it doesn't want to publish. The build output shows:

```
Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink
Compressing Blazor WebAssembly publish artifacts. This may take a while...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\..\tools\net6.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.Tool.dll" brotli
-s
C:\Users\some.user\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\SomeProject\SomeProject\Client\wwwroot\css\styles.css
-o
...
Unrecognized command or argument 'Studio'.
Unrecognized command or argument 'Projects\SomeProject\SomeProject\Client\wwwroot\css\styles.css'.
Unrecognized command or argument 'Studio'.
Unrecognized command or argument 'Projects\SomeProject\SomeProject\Client\obj\Release\net5.0\compress\HgRmrImw.br'.
...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.5_0.targets(633,5): Error MSB6006: "dotnet.exe" exited with code 1.

9>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
```

Once the publish fails, VS gives a popup box that says to check the output window for details and that a log was written to a temp location. The log isn't super helpful to me:

```
7/21/2022 3:25:18 PM
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
```

The error in the Output window looks like the path to the published file isn't inside of quotes, so VS doesn't handle it correctly. This project used to publish fine. I don't know of any project related settings that I have changed recently, just code. If I build the project in Debug or Release mode it runs fine. Are there settings that control the publish process that I should investigate? I looked through the project's settings but didn't see anything that looked promising.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk

If you don't see "6.0.100" then download it here...

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.100-windows-x64-installer

Install that and then you should see a folder appear named "6.0.100"

Rename any folders with a higher number to something else, eg. "6.0.302" to "6.0.302.dontuse"

Delete all "bin" and "obj" folders in your solution folder.

Try republishing.

Explanation: There appears to be bugs around publishing Blazor WASM apps in the newer version of the SDK.